# Setup semantic-ui-calendar once for multiple usage in multiple js files

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have Django app which uses webpack to compile frontend. As a frontend library I am using semantic-ui. Recently I have installed separate module [semantic-ui-calendar](https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar).

It is working fine. In required js file I can write

```
  $('#event_starts_at_1').calendar({
      minDate: new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), today.getHours(), today.getMinutes()),
      monthFirst: false,
  });
```

and it will init the calendar component.

The ui-calendar component uses many options which I will use. Also I have multiple pages where ui-calendar will be embedded.

I don't want to repeat the same code for ui-calendar initialization in each of js files and  looking for a solution which inits the component only once.

For me the problem looks not very complecated but I cannot figure out how to solve it with js and webpack. Probably you can provide some snippet which either subclasses ui-calendar or does something else to setup it only once. Thanks!

Comment: You could make a settings object in a separate js-file, and simply initialize the calendar html elements with that object, or even a separate javascript method that takes a html-element as a parameter. But then you'd have to include/import that js file into all of your html pages. I do things like this a lot, and have sort of different template js-files with constants etc.

Comment: Why not just write the calendar code in a file and include it in your header/footer to make it available everywhere?

Comment: @jovan yes, I think it is done. The calendar js and css is loaded into each of the pages where it is required. But additionally I have multiple js files where I have to initialize calendar for each html id and I don't want it.

Comment: @KjetilNordin I tried to split the settings into a separate js file but having difficulties in the moment with injection of var with settings into webpack js which should be compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are aleady using JQuery, so here is a suggestion. Note that there are several different ways of doing this, and this is only one approach.

If you do not wish to initialize each element in its own javascript, as you have written in your example in the question, you can always abstract it away.

you can consider giving all of your calendar elements a classname like `semantic-calendar`. Then, in a javascript file, use a document-ready function, and a foreach loop to initialize all elements with the given class:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.semantic-calendar').each(function(){ 
        $(this).calendar({
            minDate: new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 
                today.getDate(), today.getHours(), today.getMinutes()),
            monthFirst: false
        });
    });
});
```

Note that the last comma after `false` has been removed. it shouldn't be there, as it is the last element.

Now, this javascript snippet could be included in the calendar js itself, if you have control of it. It can also be included as a seperate file, or an existing custom javascript utility collection.

If needed, you could always skip the document-ready wrapper, and put the code inside a function instead. That way you would decide yourself when the initialization happens, by calling a function, instead of it happening automatically when the DOM is loaded.